# Marker symbology on vertices ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, symbology, vertices

How can you add a custom marker/point on the vertices of a **line** feature?

There are only options to add them to the start/end of the line and equally spaced along the line.

However, a marker on the exact postition of each vertices seems not to be possible.

[image: Marker for vertices]

Answer (score 1):

This method is not dynamic but you may convert the line layer to vertex points using the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool and then style the points however.